# Using Next JS and Typescript page to parse and render JSON returned into Objects as a Place

Tags: json, typescript, next.js

Using Next JS version: 14.1.1 with Typescript

How do I replace this code:

```
{placeObjects[0][0].map((myplace) => (
```

With something that returns all places objects like below which doesn't work.

```
{placeObjects.areas.map((myplace) => (
```

Json console debug

```
{
  district: 'Lagoa',
  council: 'Carvoeiro',
  areas: [
    { area: 'Val Milho', activities: [Array] },
    { area: 'Downtown Carvoeiro', activities: [Array] }
  ]
}
```

My Places.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ClientPagination from '@/components/client-pagination';
import Place from '../../model/place';
import PlaceTile from '../../components/PlaceTile';

  export default async function PlacesPage(props:any) {
    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/places");
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.debug("Place page returned new carvoeiro data");
    console.debug(data);
    // {JSON.stringify(data)}
    const placeObjects = data.areas.map((area) =>
    area.activities.map((activity) =>
      activity.places.map((place) =>
        Place.createPlace(
          activity.type,
          place.uid,
          place.name,
          data.district,
          data.council,
          area.area,
          place.description,
          place.photoName,
          place.tags,
          place.activity
        )
      )
    )
  );

  // Iterating through the array of areas
  data.areas.forEach((area) => {
    console.log(` Iterate Area: ${area.area}`);
  
    // Iterating through the array of activities within each area
    area.activities.forEach((activity) => {
      console.log(`  Activity Type: ${activity.type}`);
    
      // Iterating through the array of places within each activity
      activity.places.forEach((place) => {
        console.log(`    Place Name: ${place.name}`);
        // Add more logic here based on your needs
 

      });
    });
});
  
    return (
      <>
        <span className="font-bold text-4xl">Places</span>
        Places Page Data works
       
        <div>
        <h1>Places List</h1>
          <div>
            {placeObjects[0][0].map((myplace) => (
                  <PlaceTile key={myplace.getUid()} value={myplace}></PlaceTile>
               ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
 
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-muted-foreground">sub heading</div>
        <div className="border-dashed border border-zinc-500 w-full h-64 rounded-lg">
        <ClientPagination></ClientPagination>
        </div>
      </>
  );
}
```

My Places API

```
// pages/api/places.ts
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export default async function (req, res) {
  // Replace this with your actual data retrieval logic
  console.debug("API responding with carvoeiro activity values")
  const data = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '/pages/api/data/carvoeiro.json', 'utf8');
  
  // Parse JSON data
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  res.status(200).json(jsonData);
};
```

Json Doc returned

```
{
    "district": "Lagoa",
    "council": "Carvoeiro",
    "areas": [
        {
            "area": "Val Milho",
            "description": "Quite peaceful residential area with many quaint white traditional villas with red and yellow tile roofs.",
            "activities": [
                {
                    "type": "supermarkets",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "1",
                            "name": "Intermarche",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["market", "food"],
                            "activity": ["shop", "eat"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "2",
                            "name": "Pingo Doce",
                            "description": "Portuguese supermarket with locations all over Portugal.",
                            "photoName": "pingo_doce.png",
                            "tags": ["market", "food"],
                            "activity": ["shop", "eat"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    
                    "type": "golf",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "3",
                            "name": "Val Milho Golf",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["golf", "nine holes"],
                            "activity": ["golf", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    
                    "type": "beach",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "4",
                            "name": "Praia Vale Centeanes",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["cliffs", "town", "excursions", "tours", "swimming", "food", "bars", "restaurants"],
                            "activity": ["swim", "fish", "sun bath", "walk"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "5",
                            "name": "Praia Carvalho",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["cliffs", "cliff diving", "swimming"],
                            "activity": ["swim", "fish", "sun bath", "walk", "cliff diving"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    
                    "type": "restaurants",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "6",
                            "name": "Gaspacho & Migas",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["Mediterranean"],
                            "activity": ["food", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    
                    "type": "walks",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "7",
                            "name": "Algar Seco",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["cliff walk"],
                            "activity": ["fish", "sun bath", "walk", "cliff diving"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "8",
                            "name": "Seven Hills Trail",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["cliff walk"],
                            "activity": ["swim", "fish", "sun bath", "walk", "cliff diving"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "area": "Downtown Carvoeiro",
            "description": "Originally a small fishing area that has become a tourist destination for families.  Many small quaint shops restaurants, bars and pubs. Pleny of places to get gifts or find real estate, lawyers and other service providers.",
            "activities": [
                {
                    "type": "excursion",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "9",
                            "name": "Carvoeiro Tours",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["boat tours"],
                            "activity": ["boat tours", "cave tours"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "golf",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "10",
                            "name": "Gramacho Golf Course",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["18-hole golf Course"],
                            "activity": ["golf", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    
                    "type": "beach",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "11",
                            "name": "Praia Carvoeiro",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["Beach", "Praia"],
                            "activity": ["fish", "sun bath", "walk"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "12",
                            "name": "Praia De Paraiso",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["Beach", "Praia"],
                            "activity": ["fish", "sun bath", "walk"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "restaurants",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "13",
                            "name": "Taste",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["international", "portuguese", "European"],
                            "activity": ["food", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "14",
                            "name": "Tasca 26 - Eat Oute - Tapas & Grill",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["international", "Mediterranean", "Steakhouse"],
                            "activity": ["food", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "15",
                            "name": "Mumbai Darbar Indian Eat Out",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["international", "Mediterranean", "Steakhouse"],
                            "activity": ["food", "eat", "bar", "music"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activity": "Walk",
                    "type": "place",
                    "places": [
                        {
                            "uid": "7",
                            "name": "Algar Seco",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["cliff walk"],
                            "activity": ["fish", "sun bath", "walk", "cliff diving"]
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "17",
                            "name": "Walk to downtown Carveiro",
                            "description": "International supermarket with locations across Portugal. Offers fresh fruit, vegtables and fish, national and international products. Open daily from 08:30-22:00 in Summer and 08:30-21:30 in Winter.",
                            "photoName": "intermarche.jpeg",
                            "tags": ["walk"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Places Model:

```
// model/place.ts
class Place {
  private type : string;
  private uid : string;
  private name : string;
  private district : string;
  private council : string;
  private area : string;
  private description : string;
  private photoName : string;
  private tags : string[];
  private activities : string[];


  constructor(type : string, uid: string, name: string, district : string, council: string, area: string, description: string, photoName: string, tags: string[], activities: string[]) {
    this.type = type;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.name = name;
    this.district = district;
    this.council = council;
    this.area = area;
    this.description = description;
    this.photoName = photoName;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.activities = activities;
  }

  getType(): string {
    return this.type;
  }

  getUid(): string {
    return this.uid;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  getDistrict(): string {
    return this.district;
  }

  getCouncil(): string {
    return this.council;
  }
    
  getArea(): string {
    return this.area;
  }

  getDescription(): string {
    return this.description;
  }

  getPhotoName(): string {
    return this.photoName;
  }

  getTags(): string[] {
    return this.tags;
}

  getActivities(): string[] {
      return this.activities;
  }
 
  static createPlace(type: string, uid: string, name: string, district : string, council: string, area: string, description : string, photoName: string, tags: string[], activities : string[]): Place {
    return new Place(type, uid, name, district, council, area, description, photoName, tags, activities);
  }
  
};

export default Place ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `flatMap` method to map each element to a new element (just like map) but then flattens the result into a new array. This is helpful because your data structure is nested: areas contain activities, which in turn contain places.

I modified your code

```js
import React from 'react';
import ClientPagination from '@/components/client-pagination';
import Place from '../../model/place';
import PlaceTile from '../../components/PlaceTile';

export default async function PlacesPage(props:any) {
    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/places");
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.debug("Place page returned new carvoeiro data");
    console.debug(data);
    // {JSON.stringify(data)}

    // Preparing the place objects from the nested structure
    const placeObjects = data.areas.flatMap((area) =>
        area.activities.flatMap((activity) =>
            activity.places.map((place) =>
                Place.createPlace(
                    activity.type,
                    place.uid,
                    place.name,
                    data.district,
                    data.council,
                    area.area,
                    place.description,
                    place.photoName,
                    place.tags,
                    place.activity
                )
            )
        )
    );

    return (
        <>
            <span className="font-bold text-4xl">Places</span>
            Places Page Data works
            
            <div>
            <h1>Places List</h1>
                {placeObjects.map((myplace) => (
                    <PlaceTile key={myplace.getUid()} value={myplace}></PlaceTile>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div>
    
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-muted-foreground">sub heading</div>
            <div className="border-dashed border border-zinc-500 w-full h-64 rounded-lg">
                <ClientPagination></ClientPagination>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```